# Amplifier humming when no source is attached

Tags: amplifier, audio

I've got a little problem with an amplifier board.
When no audio source is plugged in, there's a loud hum or buzz (rather low-frequency, I unfortunately don't have the proper measuring equipment). As soon as I plug in a source, my smartphone for example, the loudness of the hum decreases dramatically, and when I turn on music (hence sending an audio signal) it disappears completely.
I had a look on the internet, but all i could find was about the amp humming *if* there was something attached.
[This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/TDA7492-2-x-50W-D-Class-High-Power-Digital-Amplifier-Board-AMP-Board-Radiator-/162006712978?hash=item25b85a4292:g:5EoAAOSwSv1XmFLB) looks like the board I'm using.
I would be glad if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when an audio power amp is powered by an ungrounded secondary , which may be for mobile safety reasons.  Even though it may have some linear or switching power supply, the current pulses easily create a voltage in the floating secondary audio circuits. We know I*R = Voltage and thus imagine currents coupling by mutual inductance or voltage from capacitance being induced on a floating secondary.

- (power line I charge pulses) I * high Z ( floating secondary = V (noticable hum)
- this is an over simplification yet true. Thus the solutions can be;

  - turn off a laptop charger ( if using as a power amp & speaker)
  - connect a cap from audio jack to earth ground
  - wrap your hands around power cable and touch earth ground
  - use a Ferrite DC Line filter with Y caps to earth ground.

In each of these examples there is a COmmon Mode Hum field being suppressed by the low impedance ratio of the coupling impedance ( yet DC floating) to the low impedance shunting to ground.

The reason they do not ground mobile chargers is to prevent ground fault currents and a potential shock if you touched the plumbing while the electrical outlet had some unsafe leakage current from line to ground and ground was faulty. ( open) or some similar reason...

In your case , the **power supply or mobile charger is at fault for this EMI disturbance** with poor coupling capacitance in the SMPS transformer and no active PFC to reduce AC current spikes, while connecting to the power amp improves the result.

How they ever passed EMC , CE, FCC is beyond my interest, but that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like the inputs are floating. Try pulling them down to ground with a high value resistor, say 100K. See if that helps. They are picking up hum because they have no (significant) input impedance to ground, so they're just picking up any passing induced voltage.

Comment: Together with Tony Steward's solution, this decreases the noise a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a little problem with an amplifier board.

Now imagine that this board is powered from a conventional transformer, bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor. There will inevitably be ripple superimposed on that power rail. That ripple will, via amplifier biasing resistors, find its way to the input circuit (the most sensitive part). Without a strong voltage source connected to the input, that ripple could be tens of millivolts and be the problem.

So then you connect your strong voltage source and that ripple gets kind-of crushed down and the problem significantly reduces. (I can show some math if that helps)

> when I turn on music (hence sending an audio signal) it disappears
>   completely

Finally, due to the way the ear works, as soon as the music starts, the relative loudness of the much reduced hum is diminished further i.e. you might hear a pin drop onto a table but not when someone is talking to you.